# How to convert mm to xy coordiantes in pcb xy files

Tags: pcb-layers, gerber

i have few pcb gerber projects which come along xy files in txt/xlsx format , these xy files have x y values in mm/inches/mils for every element on the board.
am developing gerber editor for gerber files which will search for elements on that baord.

what i have done.

-> Gerber layer files are loaded by user

-> Gerber layer files are rendered to 600 DPI image.

-> User load xy file like: ::

> http://pastebin.com/nLpDBbES    or      http://pastebin.com/XMXS0gxg

-> then with Jquery user can goto any xy coordinates on that image.

so problem is am unable to convert correctly these xy values which are in mm/mils format to xy coordinates for windows web browsers

although for one project which have xy file : http://pastebin.com/nLpDBbES   i setuped some alogo to convert is xy value from mm to coordinates worked however its not working on other projects, so what i did is take mm x y values and multiply 12 with it and then would just flip value because xy coordinate system in web browsers would start from top left corner however in real life positive xy occur in first Quadrant which will be left bottom corner.   ... the project final rendering dimension was 1350x1107  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIwcg.png

so any PCB industry expert have worked with it , help will be appreciated .

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about processing files in software on a PC - no more about EE than a question about typesetting for an EE book would be...

Comment: @user889030 Use proper punctuation and grammar, it makes you look educated and people are more likely to answer your question. Use the image button to add your images to the question. Please also see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: sorry english is not my native language i tried my best to write correct english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive axes of an image coordinate system point right and **down**, while they point right and **up** in gerber, as you already wrote.

And an image has its origin in the upper left, while gerber also allows negative coordinates. I.e. the origin can be everywhere. Even worse, you typically know the width and height of an image, while a gerber file does not contain any information about the lowest and highest values in x and y.

For example, this is a gerber file of two rectangles drawn in EAGLE, one right and above the origin, the other left and below:

```
G01*
X000000Y000000D02*
D10*
X000500Y001000D02*

  ###   draw first rectangle ###
X000500Y002000D01*
X001500Y002000D01*
X001500Y001000D01*
X000500Y001000D01*

X-001000Y-001000D02*

  ###   draw second rectangle with negative coords ###
X-001000Y-002000D01*
X-002000Y-002000D01*
X-002000Y-001000D01*
X-001000Y-001000D01*

X000000Y000000D02*
M02*
```

Your very first step is to find out the gerber coordinate range displayed in your image, or at least the lowest values for x and y. This can be tricky, since for example coordinates can be given relative to the last coordinate.

Once you have the lowest values \$x_{low}\$ and \$y_{low}\$, you can convert given xy-coodinates  to pixel coordinates:

$$x_{pix}=(x-x_{low})\cdot U\cdot 600dpi$$
$$y_{pix}=ImageHeight - (y-y_{low})\cdot U\cdot 600dpi$$

\$U\$ is the unit conversion factor to inch, i.e. 0.001 if the gerber file uses mills, and 0.0393701 if it uses mm.

This of course assumes that the xy-values in your table are given in the gerber file coordinate system.

---

**EDIT, after looking at your gerber files from the comments:**

Here is a screenshot of your "game controller" PCB, drawn with gerbv:

[image]

The lower left corner of the boundary is somewhere at 1951/2900, far away from the origin! The coordinates displayed at the bottom are the coordinates of my mouse, pointing to the center of C18. They match well with the coordinates 2865/4040 from the  pick'n'place file. It's obvious that you have to adjust the coordinates of the parts to the offset.

You also have added an image of the board, which is not 600 dpi (at 1.25" board size, it must be about 750px wide).
Your image is rotated by 180°, which makes sense for the readability of the labels. But that's not what's in the file, and my formula have to be altered for this.

And the picture reveals that there are some pixels extra margin around the entire PCB, so the yellow lines don't touch the border. This has to be taken into account, too.

[image]

You added an other board, the "Nyx PCB". This one has the same orientation as my gerbv, making sense again. This board also has offsets in x and y, though they're quite tiny. And the image also has a border.

Comment: x y value i read from xy file like :: http://pastebin.com/nLpDBbES or http://pastebin.com/XMXS0gxg

Comment: ok i will write script to find x low and y low in xy file then will update u if it work or not :) thanks

Comment: You don't need the lowest values of the xy-file. You need the gerber-coordinates of the lower left corner of the picture! Could you show the gerber file?

Comment: ok sure :) :: https://www.datafilehost.com/d/129eda40

Comment: oh sorry ya the images i send were it 300 dpi

Comment: so can you tell me formula of pixels when   layers are rotated as the above one i rotated it 180 for value reading . thanks